# How can i change my Search View icon color?

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

I have a menu with a searchview icon named `ic_menu_search` but i can't change the color or the icon of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
      android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />



</menu>
```

I changed the icon but when i run the emulator nothing changes.I made a vector asset with a black search icon but when i run the app the search icon remains white.

How can i achieve that?Thanks

Comment: You change it when you create icon.

Comment: i changed the icon but when i run the emulator nothing changes

Comment: Same problem. Icon is black, but shows up as white when app is run on phone. It seems the people answering you so far do not understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can change in Resource manager, click in add, check if it is image or vector, in both there is the color option.

Comment: I did that but the app didn't change when i run in the emulator

Comment: however in the activity.xml it appears as black but in the emulator it's white